# Dangling DNS in Azure

Tags: azure, dns, subdomain

I got two emails from Microsoft today and they turned out to be false positive. Have you received emails with the excerpt like below? If so, did you find it was helpful or was it turned out to be a false positive alert?

*"This email notification has been sent to each Global Administrator(s) and/or Technical Contact of your Azure Active Directory tenant."*

*"Dangling Domain(s): {'aspnet4you.com'}"*

*"Our security team has identified specific Domain Name System (DNS) subdomains that belong to your organization's Azure Active Directory tenant, that have been left dangling (not mapped to an active Azure resource). We want you to be aware of this issue, as dangling DNS entries can pose a security risk."*

Glad that Microsoft provided instructions on how to identify dangling DNS records at https://aka.ms/DanglingDNSDomains. I ran the PowerShell script and found no missing CNAME. While that's great news, I am wondering how did Microsoft test before sending the alert!

You can [download](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Network-Security/tree/master/Cross%20Product/Find%20Dangling%20DNS%20Records) and run the PowerShell command and share your experience. Here is the sample results for my use case-

```
PS C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive\Azure\dangling-domains> .\Get-DanglingDnsRecords.ps1 -InputFileDnsRecords .\CNameToDNSMap.csv -FileAndAzureSubscription
WARNING: Run parallel is unsupported in the current version of powershell: 5.1.18362.752, running in serial mode

Fetched 18 Azure resources: Total time took in milliseconds: 3099
WARNING: Please standby - processing 2 subscriptions
WARNING: Please standby - processing 0 DnsZones and 0 DnsRecordSets
Completed Azure DNS records fetch workflows: Total time took in milliseconds: 7715
No CName records missing Azure DNS records found
Fetched 18 Azure resources; Saved the file as: C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive\Azure\dangling-domains\AzureResources.csv
WARNING: No Azure DNS CName records fetched
Processed 9 CName records from input file: .\CNameToDNSMap.csv
Found 9 CName records matching in Azure resources;  saved the file as: C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive\Azure\dangling-domains\AzureCNameMatchingResources.csv
Id                                   Directory
--                                   ---------
61xx6xxx-0429-xxa3-xxxx-4bcbxxxx5aef                   

NameOfProcessSection            : Time in Milliseconds
InputFileProcessingTime         : 9
AzureLibrariesLoadTime          : 7
AzureResourcesFetchTime         : 3099
AzureDnsRecordsFetchTime        : 7715
InputDnsCNameListProcessingTime : 7
AzureCNameListProcessingTime    : 1
SummarizeTime                   : 12
ScriptExectionTime              : 11536


TypeOfRecords               : Details
ProcessedType               : Serial
AzureSubscriptions          : 2
AzureResources              : 18
AzureDnsZones               : 0
AzureDnsRecordSets          : 0
InputDnsCNameList           : 9
AzureDnsCNameRecordSets     : 0
AzureCNameMatchingResources : 9
AzureCNameMissingResources  : 0




AzureResourceProviderName AzureResourceCount AzureCNameMatchingResources AzureCNameMissingResources
------------------------- ------------------ --------------------------- --------------------------
Azure API Management                       0                           0                          0
Azure Container Instance                   0                           0                          0
Azure CDN                                  0                           0                          0
Azure Front Door                           0                           0                          0
Azure App Service                          9                           8                          0
Azure Blob Storage                         8                           0                          0
Azure Public IP addresses                  0                           0                          0
Azure Classic Cloud                        1                           1                          0
Azure Traffic Manager                      0                           0                          0
```

Comment: I got these emails too. Also received correction emails afterwards that no, there were no dangling DNS records. I went through my domains and there are no dangling records in them.

Comment: @juunas - Thanks for sharing. I happened to receive the correction email early morning today. Microsoft said they made a mistake acknowledging it was false alarm. Hope they do better job next time and not interrupt people's dinner!

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft sent correction email saying previous message was sent in error. See message below. Note that I don't pay for technical support from Microsoft and I was not allowed to create a support ticket with the tracking number provided. Hence, I had to ask my question at stackoverflow. Thank you for your feedback.

"Correction: Important security information regarding your organization's subdomain(s)

This email notification has been sent to each Global Administrator(s) and/or Technical Contact of your Azure Active Directory tenant.

You previously received an email notification titled "Important security information regarding your organization's subdomain(s)" with Tracking ID: "redacted". The previous message was sent in error as our records do not indicate that your organization has dangling subdomain(s).

No further action is required. We apologize for the inconvenience and are continuously taking steps to improve our communication processes to help prevent similar occurrences in the future."